# Smallest Gerschgorin Disk containing all eigenvalues of a transition matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $A \in M_{n\times n}$ is a transition matrix such that $A_{ii} \geq \frac{4}{5}$, what is the smallest disk in $C$ containing all eigenvalues of $A$?

I understand the concept of the Gerschgorin's Disks for each eigenvalue of this matrix. I can also intuit what's necessary here: the furthest an eigenvalue can be from $\frac{4}{5}$ is in the disk centered there with radius $n-\frac{4}{5}$, and the furthest an eigenvalue can be from $1$ (since all diagonals must be between $\frac{4}{5}$ and $1$ for the given transition matrix) is in the disk centered there with radius $n-1$.

Thus, I need to construct the smallest such circle that contains those two eigenvalues. However, I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out exactly how to prove/construct this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By transition matrix I assume you mean that the row sums are equal to $1$ and all entries are nonnegative. Thus, $\frac{4}{5}\leq A_{i,i}\leq 1$ for each $i$, and the Gershgorin disks are $$D_i=\{z\in\mathbb C:|z-A_{i,i}|\leq r_i\}$$ where $0\leq r_i\leq \frac{1}{5}$ since $r_i$ is the sum of the absolute values of the off-diagonal entries in the $i$-th row.

Comment: Actually the column sums are equal to $1$ by the definition of a transition matrix I'm working with, so in this case it's possible for the max row sum to equal $n$, which means $0 \leq r_i \leq n-\frac{4}{5}$. I have these disks for each eigenvalue, but I need to construct a disk that contains ALL eigenvalues...

Comment: Well this is fine: Gershgorin's theorem also says $r_i$ being the sum of the $i$-th column also works. This is because the eigenvalues of $A$ are the same for $A^T$.

Comment: I agree, and that was my first approach... but can we do that without loss of generality, since Gerschgorin's theorem specifies the matrix $A$ in its wording? 

Supposing we can, though, I still need to find a way to build a disk containing all the eigenvalues, not just construct each disk individually. The smallest disk containing the union of all the disks will do it, I guess.

Comment: There's no loss of generality by looking at column sums rather than row sums, because the eigenvalues of $A$ and $A^T$ are identical, so we can just replace $A$ by $A^T$ in the statement of Gershgorin's theorem. And the disk around $\frac{4}{5}$ with radius $\frac{1}{5}$ will always contain all of these Gershgorin disks.

Comment: Right, of course, because the disk centered at $1$ would have to have radius $0$ in order for the row sums to still be equal to $1$, and so on. 

I think all I needed was reassurance that the substitution of $A$ with $A^T$ was permissible. Thanks a bunch.